# iframe doesnt show up on my DIV

Tags: html, iframe

Im new to iFrames, and looking to show an iFrame inside a DIV on my page. everything looks good, when i load the page. but the Iframe doesnt show up (is see that it's loading in the backend and the DOM) but never showup it's hidden i think. Even Nothing from the code when the page loads says this..

```
 <div style="overflow:hidden" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <iframe frameborder="0" class="img-thumbnail" id="frame" sandbox="allow-
scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-forms allow-same-origin" 
style="height: 389.233px;" src="http://www.yoman.com"></iframe> 
    </div>
```

Comment: can you post your css or a working example?

Comment: Hey Brino, i removed all the CSS to try to get a solution without success.

Answer (score 0):

you must set embed true , to do this add `/embed` to your link :

```
 <div style="bottom: 0px;" id="frame-container">
  <div id="frame-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div style="overflow:hidden" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <iframe frameborder="0" class="img-thumbnail" 
        id="frame" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-forms allow-same-origin " style="height: 389.233px;" 
        src="http://www.yoman.com/embed"></iframe> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

for more info refer this link:

[Overcoming “Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options#answer-7469997)

Comment: even with embed it doesnt show up.. However, when i removed the id = "frame". it shows up... realy weird